# Mess with a systems hardware with Java?

Tags: java, hardware, system

Is there a way that, using java, I can mess with my systems harware? Say like pop open the disk tray, eject a flash drive or even capture the data being read from a CD or being stored to a harddrive? If so how far does this privilege go and do I need an API for it? Assuming that all system privileges allow for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within Java itself, because that isn't platform independent. People have used hacks in the past, the most common being calling some external VBScript (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0574.html).

You could also create your own native library and use JNI to invoke the function.

Comment: So I would write what I want to do in C(++) and have the java app call the c code?

Comment: Yes.  That's the basic idea.  But beware that if you get something wrong you can destabilize your JVM ...

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) (http://jna.java.net/) to access DLLs etc.